# How to receive Whatsapp notification without vibration?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am using Sony Xperia X, Android 6.0.1.

I have only managed to turn off the vibration of single and group chat messages by selecting "Off" under Vibrate and "Silent" under Notification tone.

The phone will **still** vibrate if I choose off under vibrate, and other than silent options under notification tone.

However, now without vibration, there isn't notification either whenever someone sends me a message. I am trying to receive message notification without vibration.

Such a simple permutation and I can't believe that I am still having trouble doing it.... OMG

Just tried on my Windows phone, same situation. Have to switch off whatsapp notification **and** vibration. Switching off vibration alone won't stop the phone from vibrating.

Comment: Maybe there is a vibration option from the Whatsapp application preferences or options?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android's built-in permission framework `appops`. From `adb shell` execute command:

```
~$ appops set com.whatsapp VIBRATE deny
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `settings->notifications->vibrate` to "off" for both "Message Notifications" and "Group Notifications" works for me. (And yes, I still have a ringtone selected, and I hear that when a message arrives.) What version of WhatsApp are you using? Latest (as of 12 Aug 2016) is 2.16.207.

Comment: yup mine is 2.16.207

Comment: If i switch my phone to be on ringtone, no issues. I am able to receive notification without vibration.

Comment: why can't they make it possible to receive notification without vibration under my phone with no ringtone mode??? I don't want to switch on ringtone.

Comment: I think that's an OS implementation, and WhatsApp uses the implementation to alert you to an incoming message, no matter what profile your phone is in. It will vibrate if the phone is on silent.